# How to make Qt widgets fade in or fade out?

Tags: qt, animation, opacity, fadeout, qpainter

I am trying to fade in and fade out a `QLabel` or for that matter any `QWidget` subclass. I have tried with `QGraphicsEffect`, but unfortunately it works well only on Windows and not on Mac.

The only other solution which can work on both Mac & Windows seems to be having my own custom `paintEvent` where I set the opacity of `QPainter` and also define a `Q_PROPERTY` for "opacity" in my derived `QLabel` and change the opacity through `QPropertyAnimation`.

I am pasting below the relevant code snippet for your reference. I still see an issue here - reusing the `QLabel::paintEvent` doesn't seem to be working, it works only if I do a complete custom painting using the `QPainter`, but that doesn't seem to be an easy way and if I need to do that for every `QWidget` subclass I want to fade out, that's a nightmare. Please clarify if I am doing any obvious mistakes here.

```
Q_PROPERTY(qreal opacity READ opacity WRITE setOpacity)

void MyLabel::setOpacity(qreal value) {
    m_Opacity = value;
    repaint();
}

void MyLabel::paintEvent((QPaintEvent *pe) {
    QPainter p;
    p.begin(this);
    p.setOpacity();
    QLabel::paintEvent(pe);
    p.end();
}

void MyLabel::startFadeOutAnimation() {
    QPropertyAnimation *anim = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "opacity");
    anim->setDuration(800);
    anim->setStartValue(1.0);
    anim->setEndValue(0.0);
    anim->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutQuad);
    anim->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

Comment: The Qt API is telling you you're using it in a way it was not meant to be used. Widgets are not really great performers when you want to animate their contents like that. It may work for a proof-of-concept, but in the long run you should be using Qt Quick. Whether you use Qt Quick 1 or Qt Quick 2 is up to you, even Qt Quick 1 (the declarative module) would be an improvement over what you're doing.

Answer (score 51):

There's actually a super easy way to do this without messy `QPaintEvent` intercepts and without the tough requirements of `QGraphicsProxyWidget`, which doesn't work on promoted widget children. The technique below will work even with promoted widgets and their children widgets.

**Fade In Your Widget**

```
// w is your widget
QGraphicsOpacityEffect *eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
w->setGraphicsEffect(eff);
QPropertyAnimation *a = new QPropertyAnimation(eff,"opacity");
a->setDuration(350);
a->setStartValue(0);
a->setEndValue(1);
a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InBack);
a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```

**Fade Out Your Widget**

```
// w is your widget
QGraphicsOpacityEffect *eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
w->setGraphicsEffect(eff);
QPropertyAnimation *a = new QPropertyAnimation(eff,"opacity");
a->setDuration(350);
a->setStartValue(1);
a->setEndValue(0);
a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack);
a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
connect(a,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(hideThisWidget()));
// now implement a slot called hideThisWidget() to do
// things like hide any background dimmer, etc.
```

Comment: I really like this answer! Although, is there a simple method in fading multiple widgets in/out?

Comment: **important** If running this code in python, you need to save the `a` and `eff` variables (`self.a=`) so they don't get garbage collected

Answer (score 2):

Try expose some part of palette as property of label then animate it:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor)

void MyLabel::setColor(const QColor &value) {
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setBrush(QPalette::WindowText, value);
    setPalette(palette);
}

QColor MyLabel::color() {
    return palette(QPalette::Normal, QPalette::Window).
}

void MyLabel::startFadeOutAnimation() {
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(label, "color", this);
    QColor c = label->color();
    animation->setKeyValueAt(0, c);
    c.setAlpha(0);
    animation->setKeyValueAt(1, c);
    animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutQuad);
    animation->setDuration(1000);
    animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

You can try avoid subclassing by defining and registering new interpolator which will handle QPalette [qRegisterAnimationInterpolator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariantanimation.html#qRegisterAnimationInterpolator), but this is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your widgets into a `QGraphicsScene`. It supports opacity changing and animation.

See `QGraphicsProxyWidget` documentation for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry i can't write it in C++, but the implementation in python3 and in C++ is the same:

You can create a QVariantAnimation animating a float value representing the opacity, connecting the `valueChanged` signal to a custom function:

```py
anim = QVariantAnimation()
anim.setStartValue(.3)
anim.setEndValue(.6)
anim.setDuration(900)
anim.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.InOutQuad) # Not strictly required, just for the aesthetics
anim.valueChanged.connect(lambda opacity: mySpecialFun(opacity))
anim.start()
```

Then, define the custom function which changes the opacity (or the property you want to animate):

```py
def mySpecialFun(opacity: float) -> None:
    mywidget.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, {color});")
```

The reason for this to work is that **we are not animating a property**. Instead, we are animating a float value, but the key is that every time the float value changes we get its value and we pass it to a custom function that does our custom job *(in our case setting the opacity though the stylesheet)*