# How to animate the outline of a QGraphicsItem in real time?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I am designing a timer with Qt. With QGraphicsEllipseItem, I drew a circle and now I need to animate the QPen around this circle (change color) every second. I found QGraphicsPathItem, but I need some examples on how to move forward. Can anyone show me an example?

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

1. `QGraphicsEllipseItem` is not a `QObject` so `QPropertyAnimation` can't be used directly on this item
2. `QGraphicsItemAnimation` doesn't cover property you want to animate.

What you can do?
IMO best approach is to provide some custom `QObject` on which you could do this animation. You can inherit `QObject` or use fake `QGraphicsObject` (which is a `QObject`).

```
class ShapeItemPenAnimator : public QGraphicsObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem *mParent;
    QPropertyAnimation *mAnimation;

public:
    QPROPERTY(QColor penColor
              READ penColor
              WRITE setPenColor)

    explicit ShapeItemPenAnimator(QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem * parent)
    : QGraphicsObject(parent)
    , mParent(parent) {
       setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemHasNoContents);
       mAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "penColor", this);
    }

    QColor penColor() const {
        return mParent->pen().color();
    }
public slots:
    void setPenColor(const QColor &color) {
         QPen pen(mParent->pen());
         pen.setColor(color);
         mParent->setPen(pen);
    }

public:
    void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget = 0) {
    }

    QRectF boundingRect() const {
         return QRectF();
    }

    QPropertyAnimation *animation() const {
        return mAnimation;
    }
}
```

Now you just attach this object to your `QGraphicsEllipseItem` and set animation you need.

```
// yourEllipse
ShapeItemPenAnimator *animator = new ShapeItemPenAnimator(yourEllipse);
animator->animation()->setEndValue(....);
animator->animation()->setStartValue(....);
animator->animation()->setDuration(....);
animator->animation()->setEasingCurve(....);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am trying to understand this whole graphics in Qt. So sorry if I ask any lame questions. For now I am just trying to run your example and see what happens. So I passed QGraphicsEllipseItem to the ShapeItemPenAnimator and got this error, "invalid new-expression of abstract class"...

Comment: just implement missing methods. probably `boindingRect`.

Comment: Hi again, with property animation, the animations are pre-defined and then we start it. Here, in this case, I don't understand how it works? I have passed the graphicsview object in setTargetObject(), is that correct?

Comment: `ShapeItemPenAnimator` is just proxy object which can expose property since it is a `QObject`. It does't do anything else. Like I wrote you could inherit `QObject` with same result, but in such case memory management is harder (that is why I used `QGraphicsObject`). About property animation read its documentation. This `setTarget` I wrote by mistake it shouldn't be there (I've fixed that).

Answer (score 0):

There are several classes helping with animations of QGraphicsItem in Qt. I suggest looking into [QGraphicsItemAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemanimation.html) and [QPropertyAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html). You can use the second one to animate the color of an item. Here is an example of using QPropertyAnimation:
[How to make Qt widgets fade in or fade out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087822/how-to-make-qt-widgets-fade-in-or-fade-out)